# Data binding automatically completing Date in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, binding

I have a class `Person` with a `DateOfBirth` property of type `Date`.
This property is bound to `TextBox.Text` with a `Binding`, updating with `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged`.
If I start typing a date into the empty TextBox all is OK until I've entered some text that qualifies as a partial date e.g. entering "23/" is what the TextBox shows, as soon as I enter  the next number "23/3" the text changes to "23/03/2023", making it impossible to enter any other year.
I am using `OnPropertyChanged` as I need to enable a Save button whenever anything changes, if I use `OnValidation` then the TextBox has to lose focus first.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a [DatePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/datepicker)?

Comment: There are other date fields that can be blank, but there's no way of "picking" an empty date from a DatePicker. Also I'm not sure if there's a difference but this is Windows Forms, not WPF.

Comment: You could use `OnValidation` and handle the `TextChanged` event yourself, forcing validation if and only if the text entered should be considered a date.

Comment: I would think that you would also be able to handle the `Parse` event of the `Binding` itself and reject anything that wasn't a full date string. I've never done it in that specific scenario myself but it seems like it should work.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, I did try `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation` but it only fires when the textbox loses focus, but I want the Save button to be enabled on any change. I did have a quick look at `Parse' but as soon as there is a legit date it's a bit useless. I'm thinking of just treating it as text and worry about the value internally to the property.

Comment: *"it only fires when the textbox loses focus"*. Which is why I said that you could handle the `TextChanged` event yourself and force validation at appropriate times. That would probably mean call `Date.TryParse` and, if it returns `True`, calling `Validate` on the form. It's kludgy but I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up treating the binding as a `String` and handled the conversion to/from a `Date` in the objects property